# Magento:how to get manufacturer name in Product page?

Tags: magento

I want to display manufacturer name in product/view.phtml  .I have all used all sort of functions like

```
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer');?>
<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getData('manufacturer'));
<?php echo $_product->getData('manufacturer'); ?>
```

But none of them helped.So how to get manufacturer name in product view page .

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As mentioned above you will need to follow a few steps:

1) goto Attribute Sets, and make sure "manufacturer" is assigned to the attribute set you are using.

2) Make sure you have added some manufacturers into the attribute options.

3) Assign one of the options to your product.

Depending on your magento version this should work:

```
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer') ?>
```

I can see the error you are getting:

```
gives error Call to a member function getManufacturer() on a non-object in
```

**Are you sure you are putting this code after this line:**

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
```

Comment: Okay ,I din't add the attribute "manufacturer" in the attribute set.But when I used ` <?php echo $_product->getData('manufacturer'); ?>` ,it printed some numerical values like 1571 .

Comment: And also `<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer') ?>` dont print anything.

Comment: getData() will return an integer for dropdown attributes, you need to use getAttributeText('name'); or you could try $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('manufacturer')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);

Comment: can you refresh your indexes, you may need to as you have added a new attribute to the set.

Comment: It seems strange, have you refreshed indexes / cache too?

Comment: <?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer') ?> Works on me in the product view template, but doesn't work on the products list.

Comment: Have you made sure the attribute is set to show on listing page? Check the attribute settings

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like this to get manufacture name

```
$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('manufacture')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

Comment: gives error `<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function getAttribute() on a non-object in product/view.phtml`

Comment: if you are on product details page then it won't give any error

Comment: I use this function as well, Kenny is correct that you need to have `"Used in product listing"` as well as Andrew said you also need to have `<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>`

Comment: yes if you use in product view page then you have $_product object

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the following things
1. Your attribute code is "manufacturer".
2. "Manufacturer" attribute is added to your attribute set.
3. You have chosen attribute values in admin catalog product. 
4. That corresponding product is visible on frontend.

If all the 4 points are yes your code should work.

Comment: Okay ,I din't add the attribute "manufacturer" in the attribute set.But when I used ` <?php echo $_product->getData('manufacturer'); ?>` ,it printed some numerical values like 1571

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`$_procuct->getManufacturer();`

Comment: gives error `Call to a member function getManufacturer() on a non-object in product/view.phtml`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
  echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getManufacturer(), 'manufacturer') 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

manufacturer (and all other attributes) is part of the optionslist, which is accessible by `getOptionsList`.

Try this snippet:

```
<?php
     $_options = $this->getOptionList();
     echo $_options['manufacturer']['value'];
?>
```

Comment: Could you add more of an explanation to your answer?

Comment: manufacturer is part of the optionslist, which is accessible by `getOptionsList`. I tried it a few times to get direct access to the attribute... but it didn't worked ...  this workaround/solution works :) ... Did I get your question? O:-)

Comment: great! Now edit that into your answer. Answers with explanations are always better

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that the "Used in product listing" option for the manufacturer attribute has been set to "Yes".

After that you should be able to do

```
$_product->getManufacturer();
```

Answer (score -1):

$_product->getAttributeText('country_of_manufacture');